How to enable the user to change the size of the embedded video in CKEditor 5 (safe for the server and other users)?
The goal is to enable CKEditor 5 to resize the embedded video (safely).
(Media embed: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/media-embed.html)

Is it possible to make your own tool that would simply change the size of the embedded video (inserted via an external link), as it is done there with the image?

As far as I understand, the video (via an external link) can be embedded in CKEditor as an IFrame by allowing the Source button in the toolbar. But then with such a tool, the user can insert any JS script () into the text, which is completely unsafe.


Add a YouTube Video (CK Editor)
https://360psg.helpscoutdocs.com/article/265-add-a-youtube-video-ck-editor

Is it even necessary to check the text in CKEdotor fields (div or textfield) on the server before writing it to the database for the presence of JS scripts ( tag), because malicious code can be inserted into the code itself using F12, even if CKEditor tools do not provide such an opportunity (there is no Source button)?

I found topics where people are asking for a simple tool in CKEditor, which I mention in paragraph 1. but it looks like no one is going to implement it? Is there any separate plugin for this feature at all?
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/6593
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8204
Thanks!
